# Java String.Format() specifier 's' - strange behaviour

Tags: java, string.format

I have following code:

```
String requestString=String.format(Constants.SEARCH_SETS_API,
                             Constants.DEVELOPER_KEY,
                             "ids:".concat(setId),
                             "1");
```

where

```
public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "3ansrfnt10cggo80";
public static final String SEARCH_SETS_API = 
                                              "http://api.quizlet.com/1.0/sets?"
                                              + "dev_key=%1s&"
                                              + "q=%2s&"
                                              + "sort=alphabetical&"
                                              + "whitespace=off&"
                                              + "page=%3s&"
                                              + "per_page=50&"
                                              + "time_format=unix&"
                                              + "images_only=off&"
                                              + "updated_since=0&"
                                              + "extended=on";
```

Problem:
Problem is that there is "\n" is inserted before %3s specifier in case 3rd argument is 1 or 2  character long like "1", "12" etc. If it is 3 characters long and more like "123" etc no carriage return is inserted.

Question:
How to get rid of the carriage return before %3s argument in case it is 1 or 2 characters long?

Comment: There's something else going on, as this is not the case if you write a short test. Because `"1"` is only one character, it gets padded with whitespace; `page=  1`.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I made a mistake in formatting :(

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `%1$s`, `%2$s`, etc. What you specified in your format string is actually padding the inserted values to the length you’re giving, e.g. 1, 2, and 3 characters.

Comment: %[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion - according to this I thought %1$s means First argument should be converted to string. It looks like I'm wrong?

Comment: You didn’t specify “%1$s” but only “%1s”. You’re missing the “$” sign.

Comment: Then, I think, accepting the answer would be an appropriate response. :)